# DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: select <column> from <table_name> Processing Document

Tags: solr

I am trying to import data from relational db to Solr for indexing. 
Here is my data-config.xml :

```html
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
    driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://link/db"
    user="user"
    password="pass"/>
    <document>
    <entity name="locations_countries" query="select name from locations_countries">
    </entity>
    </document>
    </dataConfig>
```

Managed-schema.xml

```html
    <uniqueKey>name</uniqueKey>
   <field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I created core and than try to import the solr core from localhost but no column are fetched and when I checked the log I get following error:
[image]

I tried everything but nothing work and also delete and recreated the core but again same error.

Comment: I think you have not defined the fields inside the entity of data-config.xml <field column="name" name="name" />. after any change to the config files, restart the server

Comment: try by adding a where clause to the query..are you sure about the url provided inside the data-config.xml

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti thanxx for reply but this is : <field column="name" name="name" /> only needed when we need column name with perticular name like "pname" as "name".